# SetCurrentTab problems [Android]

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

Hello I receive current tab on screen rotation with following code:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
{
    return CurrentTab;
}
```

`CurrentTab` is set before (onTabChange)...

In screen rotation I log received data:

```
if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null &&                          
    (Integer)getLastNonConfigurationInstance() >= 0 &&   
    (Integer)getLastNonConfigurationInstance() < 4) 
    {
        CurrentTab = (Integer)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        Log.d(" - OOOOK", "Stevilo je: " + CurrentTab.toString());
    }
createView();
```

In createView I have following code:

```
private void createView()
{
        /** TabHost will have Tabs */
        tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

        tabHost.clearAllTabs();

        /** TabSpec used to create a new tab.
         * By using TabSpec only we can able to setContent to the tab.
         * By using TabSpec setIndicator() we can set name to tab. */

        /** tid1 is firstTabSpec Id. Its used to access outside. */

        TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1"); 
        TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec forthTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");

        /** TabSpec setIndicator() is used to set name for the tab. */
        /** TabSpec setContent() is used to set content for a particular tab. */
        firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Kanali", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_channels)).setContent(new Intent(this,Channels.class));
        secondTabSpec.setIndicator("Trenutno", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_current)).setContent(new Intent(this,Currently.class));
        thirdTabSpec.setIndicator("Opomnik", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_reminder)).setContent(new Intent(this,Reminders.class));
        forthTabSpec.setIndicator("O programu", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_about)).setContent(new Intent(this,About.class));


        /** Add tabSpec to the TabHost to display. */
        tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec); 
        tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(thirdTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(forthTabSpec);

        /** applying a theme to app */
        tabHost.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        LinearLayout linearTabHost = (LinearLayout) tabHost.getChildAt(0);
        TabWidget tw = (TabWidget) linearTabHost.getChildAt(0);

        /* style and mod tabs */
        for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
            RelativeLayout rllf = (RelativeLayout) tw.getChildAt(i);
            TextView lf = (TextView) rllf.getChildAt(1);
            lf.setTextSize(12);

            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(CurrentTab).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(CurrentTab);


}
```

The result is that I get proper tab selected, but there is always first's tab content... (Selected tab is OK, content shown is not)...

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1"); 
        TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec forthTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
```

change the above to something unique.

initialize it like this

```
Intent intent; 

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TabHome.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("alaune").setIndicator("A la Une",null)
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TabHome.class);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("photos").setIndicator("Photos",null)
                  .setContent(intent);

    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TabGallery.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("videos").setIndicator("Videos",null)
                  .setContent(intent);

    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TabVideos.class);

    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("journal").setIndicator("Journal",null)
                  .setContent(intent);    
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TabJournal.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("direct").setIndicator("Direct",null)
                  .setContent(intent);  

    tabHost.addTab(spec);  
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Don't know how I missed that one... But that still didn't solve the whole thing... 1. tab and 2. tab works great... 3. tab is just text... And when I turn screen on that one it shows blank screen below tabs (just white)

Comment: Furthermore I have noticed  that turning screen around causes, that at some point no data is displayed... Why is that?

Comment: While testing I have found that sometimes it acts as intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Currently.class); wasn't set... sometimes is OK ...

Comment: Remove the orientation changes if it causing so much trouble.

Comment: In your 3rd Tab your text might be getting behind Tab. Apply some top padding to your layout.

Comment: I need orientation, couse some data is shorten in portrait mode... 

I think that padding isn't the problem. It doesn't load the layout due to some reason...